# Run time assertion in eigen/src/Core/Block.h while using pcl::NormalEstimation

Tags: pcl, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using diamondback version of ROS on Ubuntu 10.10. I am trying to estimate the normals of the point cloud using pcl::NormalEstimation class. But on running the code, I get runtime assertion on line 278 of the Block.h file. Here's the console output:

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/eigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:278: 
Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel, true>
::Block(XprType&, typename Eigen::internal::
traits<Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel, true> >::Index) 
[with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>, 
int BlockRows = 3, int BlockCols = 1, bool InnerPanel = true]: 
Assertion `(i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) && (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) 
&& i<xpr.rows()) ||((BlockRows==XprType::RowsAtCompileTime) && (BlockCols==1) 
&& i<xpr.cols()))' failed.
```

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10383/run-time-assertion-in-eigen/src/core/block.h-while-using-pcl::normalestimation/) by [Ankit](https://answers.ros.org/users/730/ankit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is best asked on [pcl-users](http://pointclouds.org/contact.html).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0